# Hide error and warning in admin panel

Tags: 7

[image]I want to hide error and warning message from admin panel. I have checked the option None in admin panel for error reporting and still it showing error and warning messages in admin  panel. let me how it can removed.

Comment: Feature request here https://www.drupal.org/node/2743119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code suggested by [indrock](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/6461/indrock) would remove all the messages shown by the modules, not just error messages, and warnings.

What you can do is implement `THEME_preprocess_HOOK()` using the following code.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (path_is_admin(current_path())) {
    unset($_SESSION['messages']['warning']);
    unset($_SESSION['messages']['error']);
  }
}
```

[current_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7) currently returns the value of `$_GET['q']`; I am using it for compatibility with Drupal 8, as for that version [current_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!path.inc/function/current_path/8) is not simply returning the value of `$_GET['q']`.
Instead of `unset($_SESSION['messages'][$type])`, you can use `drupal_get_messages($type, TRUE)`. Using `drupal_get_messages()`, you are sure your code works even when the messages are stored in a different session variable, or a variable that is a session variable. So far, it doesn't seem necessary, as Drupal 8 uses the same session variables used from Drupal 7, for the messages.

The settings in admin/config/development/logging are for error messages caused by PHP code. They don't influence the error messages shown by modules.

Comment: this gives more control on the type of messages. A better solution ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Although it is not a good idea to hide the errors (you may want to solve it; by watching the error log, debugging etc.), there is a way you can do it.

You can do it at theme level in [`template_process_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_process_page/7) function, in your theme's template.php file. (It should be placed in your admin theme's template.php)
Code: Edited according to @Chapabu 's comments :)
Used [`path_is_admin()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/path_is_admin/7) and [`current_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7).

```
<?php

function MYTHEME_process_page(&$variables) {
  if (path_is_admin(current_path())) {
    unset($variables['messages']);
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: i think it will unset this for whole site while i want it only for admin panel

Comment: look for the edit. Don't forget to clean the caches :)

Comment: I have tried the way you mention but it still showing errors on admin panel configuration as shown in the screenshot in question...plz have a look

Comment: did you clear the caches before trying?

Comment: I have cleared the cache twice now but it still showing :(

Comment: Don't forget you'll need to put this code in the template.php for the admin theme, not the for your site theme!

Comment: Also, I'd replace `if (arg(0) == 'admin')` with `if (path_is_admin(current_path()))` just in case you're on an admin page that doesn't start with `admin` (such as the feed importer page)

Comment: @Chapabu : thank you for the suggestions! I've added the changes to the answer. Please see the edit.

Comment: Nice, I wasn't expecting an answer edit.  You have earned yourself an upvote sir ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys i have added this in admin theme which is seven but it still not working. i have print out $variable  but it does not show any indes as message. Please let me know what else i have to do . once again thanks a lot guys

Comment: It'll be helpful if you add your code (how are you implementing this). Ideally it should work.

Answer (score 3):

To hide Error and Warnings using Admin panel goto

**admin/config/development/logging**

Select **None** to hide errors.

Comment: I have tried this it did not work for me....:(

Answer (score 0):

You can only make it so that the error shows on certain usernames, because sometimes they do give out helpful information like "Module Update reminder" etc.

```
function MYTHEME_process_page(&$variables) {
  global $user;
  if (path_is_admin(current_path()) == TRUE) {
    if(!in_array($user->name,array('username1','username2'))) {
       $variables['show_messages'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

You can replace/add to array username1 and username2 with whatever usernames you would wish to show the error messages to.